# Add custom parameters to "Article Manager: Add New Article" section (Joomla 2.5)

Tags: php, html, joomla

I am writing a Joomla 2.5 template and the template articles are sorted by categories and type(video / text / images).

Each category can contain articles of any type.

What I need is to add a custom parameter in the add/edit article section where I can specify the article type.

Is this possible without editing the Joomla core since this is not an option?

Thanks

Comment: What should differ a video article from a text article? Is this custom parameter only to be used for sorting the articles?

Answer (score 0):

Use a content plugin to add the parameter.
But really it sounds like you could just use one of the tagging extensions from the JED and have those three tags.